# Calculate sum of values of an object's properties based on another object's properties generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming, javascript-objects

I want to calculate the sum of values of an object's properties based on another object's properties generated dynamically. This new object is generated based on user interactions. E.g I have an objects with following properties:

```
var valueStore = [
  { item1Price: 4.5,
    item2price: 6.5,
    item3price: 6.9,
    itemCategory: 'inventory'
  },
  { item1Price: 4.5,
    item2price: 6.5,
    itemCategory:'common'
  }
];
```

User selected object is:

```
var selectedStore = [
  {
    selectedItems: [ item1Price, item2price ],
    itemCategory: 'inventory'
  },
  {
   selectedItems: [ item1Price, item2price ],
   itemCategory: 'common'
  }
];
```

I want the sum of total price for `selectedStore` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very optimized solution.

```
var sum = 0;
valueStore.forEach(function (store) {
  selectedStore.forEach(function (selected) {
    if (selected.itemCategory === store.itemCategory) {
      var keys = Object.keys(store);
      selected.selectedItems.forEach(function (item) {
        if (keys.indexOf(item) > -1) sum += store[item];
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log(sum);
```

EDIT: also in selectedStore, your selectedItems need to be string values`selectedItems: ['item1Price', 'item2price']`

Comment: selectedStore can have multiple values. It is an array.

Comment: It will be very inefficient for large data sets.

Comment: You must iterate somehow. Do simple for loop when iterating arrays.